# Zooming using GeoGraphics

Tags: geography

Suppose I do:

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["City", {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}]]
```

What do folks do at this point to zoom in to various parts of the image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need some sort of GeoPosition that you want to zoom in on, then you can set your range:

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["City", {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
GeoRange -> Quantity[n, "Miles"]]
```

Where n is your width.

[image]

### EDIT 1

Here is a rough sketch of what a controller would look like:

```
corner1 = 
  GeoBoundingBox[Entity["City", 
  {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}]][[1, 1]];
corner2 = 
  GeoBoundingBox[Entity["City", 
  {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}]][[2, 1]];


Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{lat, lon}], GeoRange -> Quantity[zoom, "Miles"]],
 {lat, Min[corner1[[1]], corner2[[1]]], Max[corner1[[1]], corner2[[1]]]},
 {lon, Min[corner1[[2]], corner2[[2]]],Max[corner1[[2]], corner2[[2]]]},
 {zoom, 5, 1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you pick a particular GeoPosition of the city on which to zoom in on?

Comment: @David Check out the edit I just made, this is just using sliders- but with some effort you could most likely use a Locator control too.

Comment: Seriously beautiful answer. Absolutely amazing. Yes, I would like to see a locator example as well.

Answer (score 7):

Start with

```
GeoGraphics[Entity["City", {"Eureka", "California", "UnitedStates"}]];
```

[image]

DoubleClick anywhere on the above image

RightClick and choose `GetCoordinares`

Now, as you move over the image, the coordinates are displayed as a `Tooltip`

LeftClick at the position you want to enlarge (in this example Indian Island)

Ctrl-Copy the coordinates

Ctr-Paste into your notebook

> {GeoPosition[{40.7876, -124.17}, ITRF00]}

Transform into f.e.

```
GeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{40.8146, -124.169}], GeoZoomLevel -> 15]
```

Choose the appropriate `GeoZoomLevel`

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I really learned a lot by investigating your answer. Thanks so much.